# Map with leaflet: two points on the map, in the same location

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, location, marker, points

I have two points on the map, in the same location, but when I show on the map, one is superimposed on the other, not being able to see both at the same time. 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Marker Clustering plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) for Leaflet

```js
var map = new L.Map("map",{preferCanvas:true}).setView([48.86, 2.35], 12),
  tiles = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map),
  markerClusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup({
    disableClusteringAtZoom: 13
  ,animate:false
  }).addTo(map);

// Add vectors of the new type directly to MCG.
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i += 1) {
  new L.marker(randomCoords()).addTo(markerClusterLayer);
}

function randomCoords() {
  return [
    48.86 + 0.1 * Math.random() - 0.05, 2.35 + 0.16 * Math.random() - 0.08
  ];
}
```

```css
#map {
 width: 800px; 
 height: 600px; 
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#progress {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 400px;
    top: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
}

#progress-bar {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #76A6FC;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4leaflet/0.7.2/proj4leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.0.0/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.0.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.0.0/MarkerCluster.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="map"></div>
    <span>Mouse over a cluster to see the bounds of its children and click a cluster to zoom to those bounds</span>
```

**Update**

You can use [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) : It dynamically add/remove groups of markers from Marker Cluster.

[Live Demo](https://ghybs.github.io/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport/examples/mcgLayerSupport-controlLayers-realworld.388.html)

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks. I have one layer of Pediatrics and another layer by Dentist. When I click on Pediatrics it shows on the map all the locations in the city that has Pediatrics, and so also for Dentist.
What happens that a particular place Rua X, number 1 offers both services, and if I click on Pediatrics and then Dentist, Dentist overwrites Pediatrics. As they are points in the same place, do not show both.
And each point is from a different layer.

L.markerClusterGroup could only use for points of the same layer.

Do you know how I can do it?